# Overriding pre-defined answer in ChatterBot

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

I want to specify my own answer to a particular question for a chat bot written using `ChatterBot` library. Here is my code

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

# Create a new chat bot named Charlie
chatbot = ChatBot(
    'Charlie',
    trainer='chatterbot.trainers.ListTrainer'
)

chatbot.train([
    "who are you?",
    "I'm a friendly chat bot"
])

# Get a response to the input text 'who are you?'
response = chatbot.get_response('who are you?')

print(response)
```

The output after running this piece of code is

*Who? Who is but a form following the function of what*

instead of

*I'm a friendly chat bot*

So it looks like there is a pre-specified answer to this question embedded in the library. How can I configure a bot that will use only my answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidBankom The bot will train only with your data. The code snippet also tells same thing from [source code](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/chatterbot/chatterbot.py#L72).

```
# Use specified trainer or fall back to the default
trainer = kwargs.get('trainer', 'chatterbot.trainers.Trainer')
TrainerClass = utils.import_module(trainer)
self.trainer = TrainerClass(self.storage, **kwargs)
self.training_data = kwargs.get('training_data')
```

I think the behavior your are seeing due to [pertained database exists](https://github.com/gunthercox/chatterbot-corpus/blob/d54215a01120fbbc16d2473ee40d74069316d5d5/chatterbot_corpus/data/english/conversations.yml) in your environment.

Could you please try to delete your sqlite database file, I think in your case it could db.sqlite

```
default_uri = "sqlite:///db.sqlite3"
```

Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Specific Response Adapter. Below is the sample code. You can find more on this link: http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/index.html

{
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.SpecificResponseAdapter',
            'input_text': 'Help me!',
            'output_text': 'Ok, here is a link: http://chatterbot.rtfd.org'
        }